# Why can't I edit Views in Drupal 6 since moving the site?

Tags: views, 6, nodes

I moved a Drup-al 6 site from one hosting server to another, exporting and re-importing the DB. Everything works well but for some reason I can't edit anything in the views. Each time it says page not found which is really odd. Has something happened with paths?

I've tried rebuilding menu structures and cleared all caches etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you made sure to enable Views UI and turn on Clean URLs?

Comment: check after clearing cache

Comment: Hi both thanks for your answers but yes already done those things.

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to access?

Comment: Are you getting all the other `URL`s working ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something went wrong with SQL queries when importing the DB. Can you check if views_display and views_object_cache tables are consistent?

I would try to export each view using the Export function from the old site and then import those in the new site.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the Jquery version for the administration pages, change it to version number 1.7 instead of 1.9 and it will work.

Comment: Hi. If you are using jQuery Update, it would be nice to mention that. Also, is this feature in release now? Last time I checked it was dev-only thing.